# DynamoDBMappingException: no HASH key value present

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I have a class named SampleEntity i.e a POJO which will help me create my dynamoDB table.The hash key and range key have been defined clearly in POJO object but still i get an exception that the hash key is not being defined

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "sampletable1")
    public class SampleEntity  {

    public static final String HASH_KEY = "f1_hash";
    public static final String RANGE_KEY = "f2_range";

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = HASH_KEY)
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private Integer feild1;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = RANGE_KEY)
    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    private String field2;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "f3")
    private String feild3;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "f4")
    private String feild4;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "f5")
    private String feild5;


    public Integer getFeild1() {
        return feild1;
    }

    public void setFeild1(Integer feild1) {
        this.feild1 = feild1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getFeild3() {
        return feild3;
    }

    public void setFeild3(String feild3) {
        this.feild3 = feild3;
    }

    public String getFeild4() {
        return feild4;
    }

    public void setFeild4(String feild4) {
        this.feild4 = feild4;
    }

    public String getFeild5() {
        return feild5;
    }

    public void setFeild5(String feild5) {
        this.feild5 = feild5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SampleEntity)) return false;

        SampleEntity that = (SampleEntity) o;

        if (!getFeild1().equals(that.getFeild1())) return false;
        if (!getField2().equals(that.getField2())) return false;
        if (!getFeild3().equals(that.getFeild3())) return false;
        if (!getFeild4().equals(that.getFeild4())) return false;
        return getFeild5().equals(that.getFeild5());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getFeild1().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getField2().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getFeild3().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getFeild4().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getFeild5().hashCode();


           return result;
        }
}
```

This my class and i am issuing a create table request on this class but i got DynamoDBMappingException that is no HASH key value present.

```
server = ServerRunner.createServerFromCommandLineArgs(new String[]{"-inMemory", "-port", "8005"});
server.start();
dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("any", "thing")).withEndpoint("http://localhost:8005");

dbMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = ddbMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(SampleEntity.class);
createTableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 5L));
        dynamoDBClient.createTable(createTableRequest);
        SampleLoginEntity data= new SampleLoginEntity();
        data.setLogin(123);
        data.setField2("range");
        data.setFeild3("abc");
        dbMapper.save(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible issues I can see (one that I ran into recently), but your setup is a little different than mine.

You're using both @DynamoDBAttribute and @DynamoDBHashKey on a single item - that's not necessary, and might be messing it up, though I don't have time to test it right now. You should be able to just do, `@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName=HASH_KEY)` and you'll be fine. I think as is, you might be declaring an attribute as "f1_hash", and a hash key named as "field1", both mapping to the same internal value (though I could be wrong).

The issue I was having though is actually a result of this error message being really poorly worded - it will throw this exception when you call `dbMapper.save()` with an object with the hash key value set to null, though if your `setLogin()` was supposed to be `setField1()` that shouldn't be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exeption when tried to get the record by the `null` hashCode:

```
myClassMapper.load(MyClass.class, null))
```

Try to set:

```
        data.setField1("some_hash");
```